# Over flow scroll not working

Tags: css

```css
.main-content{
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.profile-banner{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7vw;
  margin-top: 7%;
  background-color: rgba(71, 135, 195, 0.5);
}

.profile-avatar{
  width: 18%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  img{
    width: 100%;
    border: solid white 2px;
  }
}

.profile-username{
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: $font-blue;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

.profile-second-sec{
  margin-top: 8%;
  height: 20vw;
  background-color: blue;
}

.profile-third-sec{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 8%;
  height: 30vw;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap

}

.profile-image-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
<div class="tab-header font-large">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i> User profile
</div>
<div class="profile-banner flerowspb">
  <div class="profile-username">
    User profile 
  </div>
  <div class="profile-avatar">
   Avatar image
  </div>
</div>

<div class="profile-second-sec">

</div>

<div class="profile-third-sec">
  >> This is where the images go <<
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: added in code snippit, Hope it helps

I trying to create a horizontal scroll div but when i add the content images all it does is squeeze all the images inside of it like so,

[image]

So its resizing the images to fit in but i would like them to be normal size and be able to scroll.

Now i tried to add overflow scroll but its not having that effect

```
  .profile-third-sec{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 8%;
    height: 30vw;
    background-color: $font-grey;
    overflow-x: scroll;

  }

  .profile-image-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Now i thought i knew enough on this to be able to do but obviously not! So any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try add `white-space: nowrap` for the container?

Comment: @sol Just tried that, its had no effect unfortunatly

Comment: Can you create a demo/snippet with the full code you're working with?

Comment: @sol Ok, i need to figure out how to do that.. ill do it now quickly

Comment: @sol right ive added in a snippit, wasnt sure how to add in the images though... hope thats enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `flexbox` rules. Then provide the image with some properties. Using `white-space` and `overflow` should work for you.

example:

```css
.main-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.profile-banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7vw;
  margin-top: 7%;
  background-color: rgba(71, 135, 195, 0.5);
}

.profile-avatar {
  width: 18%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid white 2px;
  }
}

.profile-username {
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: $font-blue;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

.profile-second-sec {
  margin-top: 8%;
  height: 20vw;
  background-color: blue;
}

.profile-third-sec {
  margin-top: 8%;
  height: 30vw;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.prgile-third-sec img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.profile-image-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="tab-header font-large">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> User profile
  </div>
  <div class="profile-banner flerowspb">
    <div class="profile-username">
      User profile
    </div>
    <div class="profile-avatar">
      Avatar image
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="profile-second-sec">

  </div>

  <div class="profile-third-sec">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex have default wrap property, you can try on your code based on following stylesheet.

```
.className {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

.class {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```